# Child-to-Parent Relationship

Tags: soql, relationships, childrelationship

when i am query the  Child-to-Parent relationship(contact to account) relationship field(account.name) showing value is = (null account)

My query :

```
select name,account.name from contact
```

but parent-to-child relationship ( account to contact) relationship field(contact.name) showing empty.

why child to parent relationship field value is showing (null account) ?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the error? What is the full error message? I got no issue with your query.

Comment: In Developer console --> Query Editor

Comment: check your permission in that case

Comment: i didn't get @Lance Shi

Comment: Check your field level security, object security, etc. It should be access issue IMO